# Convert coffee to javascript and show the result to standard output in Emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, coffeescript

I want to use `coffee` command from `smart-compile` in Emacs.

So I need to output converted javascript to standard output.
But I couldn't find the command line option for it.

Is there a any way for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand your workflow, but here an attempt to answer, assuming you are compiling with `M-x compile`:  in the prompt, enter `coffee -p yourFile.coffee`. It will output the compiled JS into the compilation buffer.

`coffee -h` ->   `-p, --print        print out the compiled JavaScript`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want to know!